# Do I need to manually deploy a superseded application in SCCM? Or do superseded applications automatically update to the superseded version?

Tags: deployment, update, sccm, application

I've been playing around with SCCM for Application deployment and I'm very confused as to how the Supersedence feature works.

If I already have an active deployment for Version 1 of Application A and I then set Version 2 to supersede it, *i.e. after deploying Version 1*, should all existing installations of Version 1 be upgraded to Version 2 without the need to create a Deployment for Version 2? Or do I need to manually re-deploy Version 2 to all collections that Version 1 was deployed to previously in order for the upgrade to be performed?

For the record, I'm using SCCM build 1910 and I'm interested in ***Required installations only***. A quick Google search shows that there has been issues with Supersedence in relation to Available installations, but I can't find anything on Required installations.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asked this question over on [Reddit also and I got a number of responses](https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/g2i0uk/do_i_need_to_manually_deploy_a_superseded/). In short, the superseding version of the application needs to be deployed after specifying the supersedence relationship. I seen a number of YouTube videos showing that this was the case, but the [Microsoft documentation on supersedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/apps/deploy-use/revise-and-supersede-applications#application-supersedence) doesn't actually mention the need to deploy the latest version, hence my question.

Perhaps the best explanation in the answers provided was the following (courtesy of Reddit user [flipped_bits](https://www.reddit.com/user/flipped_bits/)):

*Think of supersedence like this - it tells the client devices what to do when you deploy the new version (version 2 in your case) and those clients happen to have the old version (version 1). Your supersedence rule will tell it to either install version 2 without touching version 1 or to uninstall version 1 prior to installing version 2. **Nothing will actually happen until you deploy version 2.**
Without the supersedence rule, when you deploy version 2, it will not care about version 1. This might be OK if version 1 is no longer being deployed. But if you still deploy version 1 and then deploy version 2 without supersedence, the deployments will fight each other.*

In hindsight, I think my confusion stems from the fact that making Revisions to an application with Active Deployments results in the application being re-installed automatically on any Clients that it was deployed to previously. I assumed this would also be the case when specifying a superseding application - evidently not as all answers received point towards the need to deploy the superseding version of an application, in order to replace the superseded version.